# Xcode SwiftUI - display information from two connected items

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, datamodel

I’m working on a simple app where I’m trying to do the following.

Basically, I have boats, and I have work orders, structured like this:

Boat

- Id
- Name
- Description

Work order

- Id
- Title
- Description
- Boat Id

So every work order is linked to a boatId. I would like to display a work order details view with the following info:

WorkOrder Detail View

- Display work order title
- Display work order description
- **Display boat name**

I tried different ways to do it, my blocking point is that I’m using the MVVM format and I’m having trouble with the navigate to from my list of work orders… I tried adding @ObservedObject var bcvm : BoatCellVM in my WorkOrderDetail.swift view and try to get the Boat name from the boat ID on my work order, but that didn’t work (I get an error on the WorkOrderList.swift, saying that I should pass the argument bcvm:BoatCellVM but that doesn’t work either (other types of errors)).

Right now the WorkOrderDetails page displays the boatId: (wocvm.workorder.boatId), I could inject the boat name in the work order data model but I don't want to do it in case the name of the boat is changed for example. I want to do this via the boat id.

Here’s my code:

BoatListVM.swift

```
import SwiftUI
import Combine

class BoatListVM: ObservableObject {
    @Published var BoatRepository = BoatRepository()
    @Published var BoatCellVMs = [BoatCellVM]()
    private var cancellables = Set<AnyCancellable>()
    
    init() {
        BoatRepository.$boats
            .map { boats in
                boats.map { boat in
                    BoatCellVM(boat: boat)
                }
            }
            .assign(to:\.BoatCellVMs, on: self )
            .store(in: &cancellables)
    }
    
    func addboat(boat: Boat) {
        BoatRepository.addboat(boat)
    }
}
```

BoatCellVM.swift

```
import Foundation
import Combine

class BoatCellVM: ObservableObject, Identifiable {
    @Published var BoatRepository = BoatRepository()
    @Published var boat : Boat
    var id = ""
    @Published var completionstateiconname = ""
    private var cancellables = Set<AnyCancellable>()
    init(boat: Boat) {
        self.boat = boat
        $boat
            .map {boat in
                boat.completed ? "checkmark.circle.fill" : "circle"
            }
            .assign(to:\.completionstateiconname, on: self)
            .store(in: &cancellables)
        
        $boat
            .compactMap {boat in
                boat.id
            }
            .assign(to:\.id, on: self)
            .store(in: &cancellables)
        
        $boat
            .dropFirst()
            .debounce(for: 0.8, scheduler: RunLoop.main)
            .sink { boat in
                self.BoatRepository.updateboat(boat)
            }
            .store(in: &cancellables)
    }
}
```

Work order list VM

```
import Foundation
import Combine

class WorkOrderListVM: ObservableObject {
    @Published var workorderRepository = WorkOrderRepository()
    @Published var WorkOrderCellVMs = [WorkOrderCellVM]()
    private var cancellables = Set<AnyCancellable>()
    
    init() {
        workorderRepository.$workorders
            .map { workorders in
                workorders.map { workorder in
                    WorkOrderCellVM(workorder: workorder)
                }
            }
            .assign(to:\.WorkOrderCellVMs, on: self )
            .store(in: &cancellables)
    }
    
    func addworkorder(workorder: WorkOrder) {
        workorderRepository.addworkorder(workorder)

    }
}
```

WorkorderCellVM.swift

```
import Foundation
import Combine

class WorkOrderCellVM: ObservableObject, Identifiable {
    @Published var workorderrepository = WorkOrderRepository()
    @Published var workorder : WorkOrder
    var id = ""
    @Published var urgentstateiconname = ""
    private var cancellables = Set<AnyCancellable>()
    init(workorder: WorkOrder) {
        self.workorder = workorder
        $workorder
            .map {workorder in
                workorder.urgent ? "checkmark.circle.fill" : "circle"
            }
            .assign(to:\.urgentstateiconname, on: self)
            .store(in: &cancellables)
        
        $workorder
            .compactMap {workorder in
                workorder.id
            }
            .assign(to:\.id, on: self)
            .store(in: &cancellables)
        
        $workorder
            .dropFirst()
            .debounce(for: 0.8, scheduler: RunLoop.main)
            .sink { workorder in
                self.WorkOrderrepository.updateworkorder(workorder)
            }
            .store(in: &cancellables)
    }
}
```

WorkOrderList.swift

```
import SwiftUI

struct WorkOrderList: View {
    @ObservedObject var wolvm = WorkOrderListVM()
    
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack(alignment: .center) {
            List {
                ForEach(wolvm.WorkOrderCellVMs) { WorkOrderCellVM in
                    NavigationLink(destination: WorkOrderDetails(wocvm: WorkOrderCellVM)) {
                        WorkOrderCell(wocvm : WorkOrderCellVM)
                    }
                }
                .padding()
            }
            .listStyle(InsetListStyle())
            
            
        }
        
        .navigationBarTitle("Work Orders", displayMode: .inline)
        .navigationBarHidden(false)
    }
}
```

WorkOrderDetails.swift

```
import SwiftUI

struct WorkOrderDetails: View {
    @ObservedObject var wocvm: WorkOrderCellVM
    @ObservedObject var wolvm = WorkOrderListVM()
    @ObservedObject var blvm = BoatListVM()

    
    @State var presentaddworkorder = false
    var onCommit: (WorkOrder) -> (Void) = { _ in }
    var boatId = ""
    
    var body: some View {
            VStack {
                TextField("Enter work order title", text: $wocvm.workorder.title, onCommit: {
                    self.onCommit(self.wocvm.workorder)
                })
                .font(.title)
                HStack {
                    TextField("Enter problem description", text: $wocvm.workorder.description, onCommit: {
                        self.onCommit(self.wocvm.workorder)
                    })
                }}
                .padding()
                .font(.body)
                .foregroundColor(.secondary)
                Spacer()
                .navigationBarTitle(wocvm.workorder.boatId, displayMode: .inline)
            }
        
    }
```

Thank you.

Comment: Too much here for me to dig through, but I did notice right off the bat that you have a `@Published` array of `ObservableObject`s. Be aware that `@Published` won't trigger when this is updated unless you manually call `objectWillChange`. Otherwise, use `struct`s to get the updating behavior for free.

Comment: Thanks for the tip!